# Learning stochastic pattern using RNN

Tags: forecasting, keras, recurrent-neural-network

I have a pattern of count time series of vehicle demand as shown below.The time series is generated as follows:

Categorical Random Variable, x = {0,1,2} and p(x) = {0.6,0.3,0.1}

low vehicles = 1 + x , every 4 hours

high vehicles = 6 + x , every 8 hours

[image]

Is it possible for the RNN to learn the categorical distribution of high vehicles every 8 hours? and is it possible for the RNN to learn the categorical distribution of low vehicles every 4 hours?

Can the state information capture the proportion of different vehicle counts in the past time steps and also use the vehicle counts in the current time steps to predict (sample out) the correct vehicle count in the next time step after having learnt the vehicle count distribution from the training data?

How should I design the layers and number of neurons?

I have already tried one layer of keras simpleRNN (72 units) and one dense (linear) output layer but it can only the two periods of 4 hours and 8 hours but not the vehicle count distribution. It is shown below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to capture this pattern using pytorch DeepAR for two nbinom values (n=9,p=0.5) and (n=4,p=0.75) with period of 8 hours for each. The two signals are interleaved like below.
[image]

Run My_demo.ipynb to see the prediction of means of the two frequencies in the following repo.

https://github.com/JosePeeterson/2_freq_nbinom_LSTM/tree/master